# unable to install pytube package in anaconda?

Tags: python, anaconda, conda, pytube

```
(base) C:\Users\pa***>conda install pytube
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.
PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are not available from current channels:
  - pytube
```

Current channels:

- https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/win-64
- https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/noarch
- https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/win-64
- https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/noarch
- https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/msys2/win-64
- https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/msys2/noarch
- https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/win-64
- https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/noarch

To search for alternate channels that may provide the conda package you're
looking for, navigate to

```
https://anaconda.org
```

and use the search bar at the top of the page.

Comment: Did you do what the error message suggests and search at anaconda.org?

Comment: You really shouldn't use the base environment for development.

Answer (score 1):

The reason why the `pytube` is not being installed is beacause the package doesn't exist in the default channels. However, you can try installing from other channels:

`conda install -c everwho pytube`

In the above command, the pytube package is fetched from channel named `everwho` (suppported for windows).

or

`conda install -c jcadic pytube` (supported platforms: windows n linux)

Alternatively, there are more channels, which can be searched as: https://anaconda.org/search?q=pytube

Answer (score 0):

you can try pip install pytube
it doesnt matter or it sometime happens like the module doesnt work on the current module . so you can use an online ide called repl.it where you can manually install the package.And the best part is that it supports all modules